# Jquery show div from option already "selected"

Tags: jquery, dropdown

I want show div when its run without having to select first, this is my code line, I need help, thank you in advance. here's my [script fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/riagil/Lxdkqb4c/11/)

I have successfully displayed div when the option option is change, what I want is when it's first run, the selected option that already selected appears immediately, I am searching but confused by this line of code: `$(this).find("option:selected").each(function()`.

My script before inline : 8 the option value="5" is already "selected", but when I run the code, it must change the option to sho the div. (sorry for my bad english).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use `$('#pilih-jurusan').change();` at the end of code

Answer (score 0):

```
$(object).on
```

this function will let object bind a event

you shoulde trigger that event, like this:

```
$(object).trigger(event)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add **trigger()** method for *`change`* event below of ***on change method***  like below snippet.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#pilih-jurusan').on('change', function() {
      //Your existing code
    });
    
     // Add trigger method for change event.
    $('#pilih-jurusan').trigger('change');
});
```